# What is the best way to write a completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

I am currently working on implementing In App Purchases in my app and after restoring purchases i would like to call a completion to perform an action of displaying an alert to the user. I was doing it this way and found a post that says it might not even be executed. How can I properly structure this.

```
func restoreIAPPurchases(completion: (() -> Void)) {
    if !self.canMakePayments {
        return
    }
    self.paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
    completion()
}

let alertController = UIAlertController.vy_alertControllerWithTitle(nil, message:  "Restore will reprocess your existing subscription. You will not be charged", actionSheet: false)
    alertController.addAction("Ok")
    alertController.addActionWithTitle("Restore", style: .default) {
    IAPService.shared.restoreIAPPurchases {
       UIAlertController.vy_showAlertFrom(self, title: "Restore complete", message: "Successfully restored purchase")
     }
}
     alertController.presentFrom(self)
```

Comment: plz post restoreCompletedTransactions method.

Comment: it might not return because of `if !self.canMakePayments { return }`. You are returning and not calling the completion handler

Comment: @Bista its an inbuilt in `iOS` function you can call

Comment: @Scriptable `if !self.canMakePayments { return }` only checks if a current device model is supports making payments

Comment: doesn't matter what it checks... its not calling completion. would probably be better if completion was `((Bool) -> Void` then you could do `if !self.canMakePayments { completion(false) return }` or better... `guard canMakePayments else { completion(false) return }`

Comment: @Scriptable and what line or where would you put `completion(true)` ?

Comment: There is are [specific](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506101-paymentqueuerestorecompletedtran) [functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506063-paymentqueue) that are called when the restore process is complete. As well as in your `if` statement (which would be nicer as a `guard`) you should call your completion handler from these two callbacks

Answer (score 2):

> "I was doing it this way and found a post that says it might not even be executed"

It might not be executed because you don't call the completion handler on all paths.

As Sh_Khan mentioned in his answer, you don't really need a completion handler here, you need to use the delegate methods to be informed when it completes and whether it was successful or not. But **your** particular issue with your specific code is that you are not calling completion in the if statement.

```
if !self.canMakePayments {
    return
}
```

Should probably be

```
guard canMakePayments else {
    completion()
    return
}
```

In the code you had, if canMakePayments is false then your completion code will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

The result is asynchonous here

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue)
```

or

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, 
restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error)
```

Comment: This is unhelpful

Comment: here you don't need a completion , you have to check the result of restoration with the above methods

Comment: All I want is to display an `If purchases have been restored` Thats all. I don't see why I need to do it this way.

Comment: because this process is asynchronous to contact apple servers  insert your alert success / fail according to the called method above

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I'm writing code for login and need **Completion Hander** for wait/call back after request completed.

//MARK:- @Properties

```
var signInCompletionHandler : ((_ result : AnyObject?, _ error : NSError?) -> Void)?

var viewController : UIViewController?
```

//MARK:- call login method with completion handler.

```
 func login(withViewControler viewController : UIViewController, completionHandler : @escaping (_ result : AnyObject?, _ error : NSError?) -> Void)  {
 // Write your logic here.       
}
```